# How to pass user defined variables to mysql command

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, variables, global-variables

How do I pass variables that I would have created in linux shell to the mysql command.
For example:

```
# carname=tesla-new
# echo $carname
```

I want to use the `$car-name` variable when passing arguments to MySQL commands.

This variable will come in as input from loop while iterating through a list of values.

```
mysql -u wp-supportuser -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p<mypassword>! -e 'DROP DATABASE ${carname};'
```

I need the hyphon(-) in the variable's value, else my application will accept. We get the below error when the above command is run:

```
mysql: > [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-wp' at line 1
```

How will I be able to achieve this?

Comment: `"${car_name}"` , don't use `-` inside a variable name! https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm

Comment: @User123 Yes sorry, the hyphon `-` is supposed to be in the value and not in the variable.  As in `carname=tesla-new`.  Need the hyphon to be there, cant avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a MySQL error, because MySQL does not support the usage of hyphen by itself. Instead, you need to enclose it into

```
`
```

characters. You can use it if you wrap your command inside apostrophes, like:

```
mysql -u wp-supportuser -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p<mypassword> -e 'drop database `$carname`;
```